# Use Rouche's Theorem to determine the number of solutions of the following

Tags: complex-analysis

If $0<|a|<1$ show that the equation $(z-1)^ne^z=a$ has exactly $n$ solutions in $\textrm{Re}(z)>0$.

Hint: consider $\gamma$ as the line segment from $iR$ to $-iR$ followed by the semicircle $|z|=R$, $-\pi/2\le\arg(z)\le\pi/2$, where $R>2$.

I try to use Rouche's Thm, by taking $f(z) =  (z-1)^ne^z$ and $g(z) = a$, and then consider two cases, when $|z|=R$ and when $-\pi/2\le\arg(z)\le\pi/2$, both where $R>2$, and I want to prove that in both cases $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$, for the first case is fine, but for the second I don't know how to do it.

Maybe I am not using the hint in the correct way, could anyone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your approach is fine. Consider the entire functions $f(z)=(z-1)^n$ and $g(z)=ae^{-z}$ (a bit different from yours). Then 
$z\in \mathbb{C}$ is a solution of $(z-1)^ne^z=a$ iff $z$ is a zero of $f(z)-g(z)$.

In the half-plane $\text{Re}(z)\geq 0$ we have that
$$|g(z)|=|a|e^{-\text{Re}(z)}\leq |a|<1 \tag{1}.$$
On the other hand for $\text{Re}(z)=0$, then $z=it$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$|f(z)|=|(it-1)^n|=|\sqrt{1+t^2}|^n\geq 1 \tag{2}.$$
Moreover for $|z|= R\geq 2$,
$$|f(z)|=|(z-1)^n|\geq (|z|-1)^n\geq (R-1)^n\geq 1 \tag{3}.$$
Now consider the closed curve $\gamma_R$ given in your hint. Then, for all $z$ along $\gamma_R$, $|g(z)|<1\leq |f(z)|\geq 1$ by (1), (2) and (3). Hence, by [Rouche's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), for any $R\geq 2$, $f(z)−g(z)$ has as many zeros as $f$ inside $\gamma_R$ (note that $f$ has $n$ zeros at $1$).

Comment: @Irene Gil Any further doubt?

Comment: I am thinking about it, I understand what you have done, but I don't know how to write in a proper way the conclusion by using the curve of the given hint.

Comment: By Rouche's Theorem, for any $R>2$, $f(z)−g(z)$ has as many zeros  as $f$ inside $\gamma_R$. $f$ has $n$ zeros at $1$.

Comment: But at some point R should go to infinity, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. But the property holds for any $R>2$. Any zero of $f-g$ will eventually fall inside $\gamma_R$.

Comment: I need to think carefully about it, this evening I will do it. If I don't get it, I will comment again. But thank you so much, hopefully I can do it with you help

Comment: I don't understand the way you separate the two cases for $abs(f(z))$

Comment: Shouldn't we be interested in $abs(z)$<$R$ and not $abs(z)$>$R$

Comment: Actually we need $z$ along $\gamma_R$ so $|z|=R$ suffices.

Comment: Okey, now I think everything is clear for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I revised the answer. I hope that  everything is clear now.

Comment: @RobertZ any hint if $|a|\leq 2^{-n}$ that all the zeroes are in $\{z||z-1|\leq 1/2\}$